# Compute the path integral $\int_{0}^{i}{\sin(z)}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

I'm pretty stumped on this question. This is what I've got so far.

$\int_{0}^{i}{\sin(z)}dz = -{\cos(i)} + {\cos(0)} = 1 - {\cos(i)}$.

I am using the following theorem:
Let  $D\subseteq \mathbb C$ be a domain and let $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a continuous function. A primitive of $f$ on $D$ is an analytic function $F:D \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $F'=f$ on $D$.

THM: If $f$ is continuous on $D$ and if $f$ has a primitive $F$ on $D$, then any curve $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow D$ we have that $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz = F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a))$.

Comment: That is correct, what is your problem?

Comment: oh! It is? I thought my answer was wrong.

Comment: You may want to simplify you answer. It's easy to see that the answer is actually a real number.

Comment: A comment about the use of MathJax: Don't write `$−\cos(i)$ + $\cos(0)$ =1−$\cos(i)$`, use only one math expression for that: `$−\cos(i) + \cos(0) =1−\cos(i)$`

Comment: Okay, I'll only use one math expression. Is it just easier on the writer?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, but it can be simplified further. Use the fact that $\cos z = \frac12(\exp(iz)+\exp(-iz))$, which can be proven using Euler's identity. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: $\frac12(\exp(-1)+\exp(1))$ Would this be the simplest form?

Comment: @mathnoob indeed, though of course you can write $\exp(1)$ as just $e$.